# How can I buy an e-ticket for Netherlands train if I don't have a Dutch bank account?

Tags: trains, online-resources, tickets, payment-cards, netherlands

I wanted to buy a train ticket today from the [Dutch railroad website](https://www.ns.nl/en/travellers/home).

It all worked fine, but when checking out, I was asked for my bank details and it seems that you can only pay if you have a Dutch bank account. I want to use my credit card. Is there any way how to do that?

Comment: It might not apply to Dutch railways or your situation but sometimes it is possible to buy a railway ticket on a station even in different country.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Outdated answer, it is now possible to buy tickets online with a creditcard.**

It is indeed impossible to buy tickets online at the website of the Dutch railways. One exception is maybe the international subdivision [HISpeed](http://www.nshispeed.nl/), but only if your journey involves crossing a border.

You could though buy your Dutch railway tickets online at the [Belgian Railways](http://www.b-europe.com/Travel). They use the same booking systems, and the online tickets have the same format. Only the Belgian railways do accept credit cards.

Comment: This has changed since this answer was posted years ago. Besides iDeal, you can now also use Visa, Mastercard and Amex

Answer (score 16):

Good news, it is now possible (since January 2018) to buy a train ticket with a creditcard on the website of NS.

Source: I'm Dutch.

Answer (score 10):

According to the [online instructions](http://www.ns.nl/en/travellers/arrange-and-buy/tickets-and-passes/the-e-ticket#how-to-buy-an-e-ticket) (English or [Dutch](http://www.ns.nl/reizigers/producten/losse-kaartjes/e-ticket.html)), you can only pay with [iDeal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDEAL), which is a system for online bank transactions in the Netherlands. From this, I conclude that it is not possible to pay with credit card (this is surprising to me) and thus not without a Dutch bank account.

Additional info: online tickets are not cheaper in the Netherlands. Ticket price is fixed for trips/distances, and does not depend on any other factor, such as time. Also, national trains in the Netherlands do not offer seat reservation (this is only for international trains). In other words, you will be fine by buying a ticket at a ticket machine upon arrival.

Comment: Yes I know that I'll be fine, but even here in Switzerland, I always buy print-at-home tickets, since it is just more convenient imho.

Comment: @RoflcoptrException I can imagine that it is more convenient. You can consider the "OV chipkaart" so you don't need to buy separate tickets. I would only recommend that, if you are planning to travel multiple different trips.

Comment: @Bernhard that card is now required in a good part of the country, and paper tickets will no longer even get you to the platform. So you'd need to buy one anyway, and the anonymous ones AFAIK are only available from vending machines at railway stations.

Comment: Isn't their a fixed fee you need to pay when you buy a ticket at a NS-counter?

Comment: @jwenting Where? In South Holland, it's definitely still possible to buy the old paper tickets from NS vending machines or, I assume, counters. Busses do require some form of OV-chipkaart (if only a single-use disposable card you can buy from the driver) though.

Comment: @andra Yes but not from the vending machine.

Comment: @Bernhard But do vending machines at the station accept credit cards? http://www.ns.nl/reizigers/reisinformatie/stationsvoorzieningen/voorzieningen/informatie/kaartautomaat suggests that they only accept Maestro debit card.

Comment: @annoyed I know some that do, but it is not something I would suggest, since it still is highly unlikely to find one. Schiphol and Amsterdam might be the exception

Comment: yes, around Amsterdam afaik it's now required (city busses in Almere still take other cards, those can be purchased only in the busses though). I don't go much outside the Amsterdam area by train, do know it was supposed to be the sole means to pay nationwide by last year (but wouldn't be surprised if that was delayed, it's a government program after all).

Comment: Found a [Wikipedia article (in Dutch)](http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reizen_met_de_OV-chipkaart_in_de_trein#Vervoerbewijzen_zonder_RFID-chip) detailing this. The plan is to replace the traditional paper tickets with disposable RFID cards but, as a one-time user, you could probably just ignore the difference.

Comment: This has changed since this answer was posted years ago. Besides iDeal, you can now also use Visa, Mastercard and Amex

Answer (score 8):

From January 31<sup>st</sup> 2023, it is possible to to check in to NS trains using a contactless credit or debit card . Some other regional trains and buses work as well, but at this moment not all do. Check out the list [here](https://www.ovpay.nl/en/locations).

From the [FAQ](https://www.ns.nl/en/customer-service/payment/ovpay.html):

- You don't have to do anything beforehand to travel with your debit card. So you don't have to sign up. Of course, you must have a valid debit card with which you can pay contactless.
- ... Or with contactless credit cards from Mastercard or Visa. You can also use a foreign contactless debit or credit card from Maestro, V PAY, Mastercard or Visa. Of course, you can also use your smartphone or smartwatch if you have linked your debit or credit card.

There are some restrictions, e.g. you can can only check in once, so any traveling companion will need their own card. Furthermore, it's 2<sup>nd</sup> class only, and no discount cards can be used.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, the Dutch rail system is not very user-friendly for foreigners.

In Rotterdam we tried to buy our tickets to Amsterdam via the "self-serve" machine outside the station. We found out that not only does it not take international credit cards, but it also does NOT accept Euro bills.

The total cost for 2 tickets was 28 Euros. Rather than letting me put in three 10 Euro bills (and giving me back 2 Euros for change) I had to go to a nearby casino, exchange my money for 1-Euro coins, and then put 28 coins into the machine to get our tickets. Completely ridiculous!

So, if you intend to buy rail tickets in the Netherlands, apparently the only way to do so is with a Dutch account or coins!